# Moving header to bottom in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Like the title says, I'd like to move the header (prev, next, current month) to the bottom for aesthetic purposes. Am I being a dunce and there's a way to set it in the seetings or wil I have to do it with hacky absolute positioning?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to do this.  Using the `beforeShow` option isn't going to work because when it fires the HTML for the datepicker has not yet been created.  The datepicker widget should fire a `create` event but doesn't (it's noted as a bug on the events docs - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Personally I think the cleanest way to handle this is via a `focus` event on the `input[type=text]`.  Not necessarily ideal, but this doesn't feel too hacky and works.

```
$('input')
    .datepicker()
    .on('focus', function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker-header').insertAfter('.ui-datepicker-calendar');
    });
```

**Live example** - http://jsfiddle.net/5gWrS/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do this on the top op my head:

- Extend the datepicker class and add your own HTML
- Use the `beforeShow` option to alter the DOM. Remove the header and append it to the bottom of the picker.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is the list of all the options for the jqueryui datepicker on the bottom of this page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

I can not find any option for moving the header.

I think you will have to go with hacky code.

A short code similar to the one below should move the datepicker header at the end of it's parent element, so it should be displayed below the calendar. You should execute the code while opening the datepicker overlay:

```
jQuery('.ui-datepicker-header').each(function() { $(this).parent().append($(this)) })
```